# Notepad++ replace "Save" Common File Dialog Box

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, savefiledialog

In Notepad++ (Windows 7), is there a way to disable the Common File Dialog Box when saving a file? I would like to replace it with the standard Save File Dialog Box.

Notepad++ uses this dialog box for saving:
[image]

I would like to use the following dialog box:
[image]

Adding shortcuts to "My Place" bar is not an option as I don't plan to use the Common File Dialog Box at all.

Comment: This would be really awesome.

Answer (score 23):

The feature was implemented on 2017-01-30.

Settings > Preferences... > Default Directory > Enable "Use new style save dialog (without file extension feature)".

[@Tamarindo94](https://github.com/Tamarindo94) found where the setting was a couple days ago:

- https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/176#issuecomment-299876885

Comment: I have no idea how this ever got switched off in mine, but holy cow, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: I wonder why this is disabled by default. I certainly never disabled it manually.

Answer (score 4):

From the sounds of it this feature is on the books for the next release of Notepad++ once the support for XP goes away, details here: https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/176

Answer (score 2):

I noticed in Notepad++ they still don't have Favorites but they do have Libraries. My work around was to use Libraries instead of Favorites. You can actually add a Library that points to any folder you want. In Windows File Explorer on Windows 8, I had to go to Folder Options and check to turn on "Libraries" so that I could see them. Then I was able to right click and create Libraries pointed to the folders I wanted.